# Pandas dataframe gel all rows where a set of columns are equal to zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to get all the rows where a set of columns (not all of them) are equal to zero?

For example, if I have a dataframe like this:

[image: my dataframe]

I'd like to get only the rows N and Q back (actually only these two rows with the columns U and W).

I'm trying to do something similar to this:

```
df.loc[(df == 0).all(axis=1), :]
```

But, of course, it doesn't work since not all the columns (u and W) are equal to zero.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subset:

```
cols = ['X','Y','Z']
df1 = df.loc[(df[cols] == 0).all(axis=1), :]
print (df1)
   U  W  X  Y  Z
1  c  d  0  0  0
4  i  j  0  0  0
```

Also is possible use:

```
exclude = ['U', 'W']
cols = df.columns.difference(exclude)
print (cols)
Index(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], dtype='object')

df1 = df.loc[(df[cols] == 0).all(axis=1), :]
print (df1)
   U  W  X  Y  Z
1  c  d  0  0  0
4  i  j  0  0  0
```